# sum input field with separated comma

Tags: javascript

sorry for a newbie question, i'm new on javascript.

i already sucess using auto separated thousand with comma using javascript, but my problem is when i want to sum the field, it doesnt recognize the comma ( when my number already 1000, it automatically add a , into 1,000). i already tried to replace the comma, but its still doesnt work. any suggestion for my fault?
this is some my google script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
            //this.value.replace( /,/g,"");
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {

                sum += parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g,""));
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
    </script>
```

thanks before

regards, liu

Comment: You need to clean the number before you check for `isNaN`, as that's failing.

Comment: `console.log(isNaN("1,000"))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May this solution help you?:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".txt").on("keyup", function(){
    calculateSum();
  });

  function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".txt").each(function() {
      //cleaning the number / removing commata 
      var number = this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
      //add only if the CLEANED value is a number
      if(!number.length || isNaN(number)) return;
      sum += parseFloat(number);
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  }
  calculateSum();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input class="txt" placeholder="Number 1"></div>
<div><input class="txt" placeholder="Number 2"></div>
<div><input class="txt" placeholder="Number 3"></div>
<div id="sum"></div>
```